# Laravel find out which Permissions selected in Role

Tags: php, laravel

In my web appliction i have two table `role` and `permission` and i can sync every `permission` with `role` table

i want to find out which permissions are in role's permission, because of selecting then into view, for example i have 10 permission which four items from that synced with `role` table and i want to found out them

```php
$role = Role::with('permission')->whereId($id)->first();
$permissions = Permission::all();
dd($role,$role->permission());
```

output is:

```
App\Entities\Role {#1816 ▼
  ...
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "permission" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1814 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => App\Entities\Permission {#1829 ▼
          ...
          #attributes: array:5 [▼
            "id" => 4
            "name" => "create-comment"
            "label" => "user can create a comment"
            ...
          ]
          ...
        }
        1 => App\Entities\Permission {#1826 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
  ...
}

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1812 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Entities\Permission {#1820 ▼
      ...
      #attributes: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 4
        "name" => "create-comment"
        "label" => "user can create a comment"
        ...
      ]
      ...
    }
    1 => App\Entities\Permission {#1828 ▶}
    2 => App\Entities\Permission {#1827 ▶}
  ]
}
```

as you can see `"create-comment"` permission is in role's permissions, how can i found out them?

for example:

```php
$role = Role::with('permission')->whereId($id)->first();
$permissions = Permission::get();

dd($role->hasPermission($permissions));


class Role extends Model
{
    ...
    public function hasPermission($permission)
    {
        //return which permissions are in role
    }
}
```

or using `contains`:

```html
@foreach($permissions as $permission)
    <option value="{{$permission->id}}" @if($role->permission->contains('id',$permission->id)) selected="selected"  @else '' @endif>
        {{$permission->name}} {{$permission->label}}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: In your code, `$permissions` is a collection, not a single `Permission`, so `hasPermission()`, and passing `$permissions` aren't compatible. You could do `$permission = Permission::where('name', 'create-comment')->first()`, then you could see if your role has the `create-comment` permission, via couple methods, like `contains()` or `first(function() { ... })`

Comment: @TimLewis i should search that in array or collection, for example: `@if($role->permission->contains('id',$permission->id))`

Comment: `$role->permission` is a `Collection` (although it should be `$role->permissions`, since there's many, and variable naming should always represent what is contained, `$role->permission` is singular, so it's mismatched), but yes, that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code in `Blade` resolved my problem:

```html
@foreach($permissions as $permission)
    <option value="{{$permission->id}}" @if($role->permission->contains('id',$permission->id)) selected="selected"  @else '' @endif>
        {{$permission->name}} <span class="text-danger">({{$permission->label}})</span>
    </option>
@endforeach
```